# The logic to make a progress bar countdown timer count "up" in Android

Tags: android

I can't seem to wrap my head around how I should make a progress bar fill up. I am using a countdown timer to update the progress on a progress bar making it count down until it reaches zero. Now I want to reverse the progress and have it start at zero and fill up, but how would I go about achieving that?

```
public class theCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer
{
    public theCountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)
    {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
    {
        int progress = (int) (millisUntilFinished/100);
        progressBarCounter.setProgress(progress);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish()
    {
        Button nextInstance = (Button) findViewById(R.id.run);
        nextInstance.performClick();
    }
}
```

Comment: added the code that handles the count down

Comment: @uhlm if you solve your problem please share the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `progressBar` default maximum value is `100`. I guess that you want it to progress every tick, so inside `theCountDownTimer` you should define:

```
progressBarCounter.setMax((int) millisInFuture/1000);
```

That way, if you're counting 80 seconds ( = 80,000mS), then the bar will range between 0 and 80.
Next, you can use `incrementProgressBy (int diff)` method:

```
public class theCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer
{

  public theCountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)
  {
    super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    progressBarCounter.setMax((int) millisInFuture/1000);
    progressBarCounter.setProgress(0);  //Reset the progress
  }

  @Override
  public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
  {
    progressBarCounter.incrementProgressBy(1);
  }

  @Override
  public void onFinish()
  {
    Button nextInstance = (Button) findViewById(R.id.run);
    nextInstance.performClick();
  }
}
```

I guess that you also have an error here -

```
int progress = (int) (millisUntilFinished/100);
```

Didn't you mean to divide by `1000` instead `100`?

Comment: I do believe that the "100" references the built in functionality of the progress bar having a 100 % when full

Comment: @uhlm Yes it is, but sometimes you would like to use other values. If you count 30 seconds and increament the bar by 1 on every tick, you wil reach 30/100 when the ount is over.